# Visual Studio keeps checking out LFS related files when cloning a new Git-LFS repository

Tags: git, visual-studio, git-lfs

Since about 2 weeks now my git LFS isn't working correctly with Visual Studio. Whenever I clone a repository that contains LFS files and open this in Visual Studio it says there's certain files 'changed':

[image: Visual Studio wrong files changed]

If I don't open Visual Studio and work purely with the git command line there's no issue.

Other computers I own also work fine and allow for Visual Studio to simply checkin files inside a Git LFS repository.

**What I already tried:**

1. Reinstall Git + Git-LFS
2. Use Visual Studio Installer to install Git for Windows + Github Extension
3. Completely remove the project and clone a clean instance using `git clone ...`

**Edit 1**

While doing a bit more investigation I found out that this issue only happens for one specific folder. If I clone the DS-MLUnity repository inside `C:\XGitML\DS-MLUnity` Visual Studio will create these hook files once I start it. However when I clone the repo inside another directory this doens't happen. #confused

**Edit 2**

Apparently this also wasn't the issue because now it also creates the hooks files when I clone it in another directory.

**Edit 3**

I managed to get it to work in another directory once, but now I simply can't manage to reproduce it working. Everytime I open the Git-LFS directory inside Visual Studio 2019 (or even 2017) the hooks files get created.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's some issue with where the Git directory is being detected as being.  Git LFS will query Git with `git rev-parse --git-dir` to find the Git directory.

I would try to reproduce the problem at the command line (Git Bash) without Visual Studio first.  If you can reproduce this there, then you'll want to look at the output of `git lfs env`.  That will show you several lines, including `LocalGitDir` and `LocalGitStorageDir`.  Unless you're in a worktree, those should be the same, and they should point to the `.git` directory.  `LocalMediaDir` should point to the `.git/lfs/objects` directory under your working tree.

If for some reason those don't look sane and you're sure you don't have any odd environment variables set (`git lfs env` will show you all of the Git environment variables as well), then head on over to the [Git LFS issue tracker](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues) and report an issue, including the output of `git lfs env`, your reproduction steps, and relevant OS information in your report.